# MuleStudio studio:studio goal failed to execute

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

I copied/pasted a working project in my Mule Studio workspace (from within Mule Studio) to create a new project. After that, I could do a mvn clean install on the new project and everything worked fine.

Then, after any modification on the pom (i.e. add a blank line), I'm getting the following error (On an exclamation mark over the project name). I can still execute mvn clean install without errors and obtain a jar that I can deploy. However, I'd like to eliminate the error.

> Build problem on project ProjectName, studio:studio goal failed to
>   execute, check the Maven Output console for logs

### EDIT

This is what I can read in the console

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'studio' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, mojo.codehaus.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\_jde\maven\repo), nexus (http://nexusserver00:8080/nexus/content/groups/public)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'studio' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, mojo.codehaus.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\_jde\maven\repo), nexus (http://nexusserver00:8080/nexus/content/groups/public)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]
```

**Observation:**

When I run this build on the project that doesn't show the error on Mule Studio, I get exactly the same error message.

Comment: can you run from command line `mvn studio:studio -X -e` to get more detail?

Comment: That error seems to be different from the one you get building with Studio. Probably studio is adding a jar with the studio maven plugin to the classpath or something like that. Try adding this repository definition to your pluginRepository section in your pom.xml or settings.xml:

`<pluginRepository>
     <id>mule-ee-public</id>
     <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it this way:

1. Copy the new project to another folder and remove it from current workspace.
2. In Window/Preferences/Mule Studio/Maven Settings, uncheck both checkboxes (Enable Maven Suppport and Enable Automatic Maintenance).
3. Import the project.
4. Check both checkboxes unchecked in step 2.

The error does not show anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this repository definition to your pluginRepository section in your pom.xml or settings.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    ...
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mule-ee-public</id>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>           
    </pluginRepository>
    ...
</pluginRepositories>
```

Perhaps because an Studio error this repository is not taken into account, and it is needed to download the plugin.

Comment: I can't use external repositories. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

An old thread, but maybe someone will find it useful in addition to **Ale Sequeira**'s post.

You must replace http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/ repo with https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ one everywhere. This is because the 1st repo responses with 301 redirection to the 2nd one, and Maven-2 handles that incorrectly. Maven-3 is alright though.

Answer (score 0):

Just close all other projects if you are using Anypoint Studio and then update the dependencies or run project. Worked several times in my case.