# Mule CRC32 Processor throws org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I added Mule CRC32 processor to my program. When I start it I get this exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/crc32/current/mule-crc32.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Another exception in the console:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'crc32:config'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, ........, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.

I've searched for the xsd in the link Mule automatically inserted and failed to find. "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/crc32" doesn't exist.

Do you know where I can find the xsd?

Thanks,
Keren

Comment: After research more I saw other problems in my Studio. Andres' reply helped me to solve the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554383/mulestudio-studiostudio-goal-failed-to-execute

Answer (score 1):

Did you add Any point Enterprise Security jars? CRC message processor is part of it, and does not come bundled with Mule Standalone but is a different product.

Comment: Jars? I added the plugin in the studio

Comment: Which Studio and Enterarse Security version are you using? Which runtime?

Comment: Anypoint Studio 4.1.0.201410170001 (October 2014 release), CRC32 Module (Mule 3.5.0+) 1.3.0.201405141504, runtime (if I understood correctly) is java-7-openjdk-amd64.

Comment: for the runtime I mean the Mule version you are using in your application. Also, how do you install Enterprise security in your Studio?

Comment: Mule server version is 3.3.0. I installed it according to MuleSoft's instructions: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+Anypoint+Enterprise+Security