# Configuring maven with Anypoint Studio

Tags: java, maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to setup Anypoint Studio 6.6 on my MacBook, I have been using it on windows and it works fine. I have installed Java 8 and Maven 3.6.3 and I have also set up the environment variables so I can use java and maven on the terminal and the works good. On preferences, the Installed JREs and classpath variables are all pointing to the JDK but when I try to run a project with maven, I get the error - There was an error running the studio:studio goal on project projectname.
I updated the settings.xml as instructed by the documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb, but I am still getting this error. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are to set Maven to work with Mule. You also need to [point Studio to your Maven installation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/5/maven-support-in-anypoint-studio), which I suspect you already did. For the error related to studio:studio, you should have pasted the complete error in the question, however I guess you need to add the plugins repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24557069/721855

Comment: I get first the error when I launch Anypoint Studio - There was an error populating maven local repository with the selected ESB server artifacts

Comment: Please attach the complete error message or log. If possible copy the text of the error in addition to a screen shot.